FromBody and FromHeader attributes together in .NET Core 6
I have a model RegisterCustomerRequest:
public class RegisterCustomerRequest
{
    public int Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int TenantId { get; set; }
}


public async Task<IActionResult> RegisterCustomer(RegisterCustomerRequest model)
{
    // body
}

Since it is a POST request, the key requirement is to extract the TenantId value from the HTTP request header and the other fields from the request body.

You can decorate your method like this public async Task<IActionResult> RegisterCustomer(             [FromBody] RegisterCustomerRequest model, [FromHeader(Name = "TenentId")] int tenentId) Have you tried that?

@MdFaridUddinKiron I tried it, it works. But I'm interested in any other ways of achieving it within the model definition. Thanks.

Yes, you can but would be little clumsy, because you need to do that using custom model binder.

Can you please answer the question about using a custom model binder by implementing IModelBinder? As I mentioned in the comment on @mattsharp's answer, I have multiple request models and I'm unsure how to bind them from the header to the model for multiple models.

You could use the way I did, its little way to implement rather then model binder.

Now you could try the both ways. But I prefer First way, for this scenario.

@MdFaridUddinKiron Thanks a lot. I'll definitely implement first way. Will accept it as answer once I'm done with the implementation.

Sure, have a try,


Given that it is a POST request, the key requirement is, I need to
take TenantId value from http request header, and the other fields
from the request body.

Based on your scenario and comment, yes you could achieve that using either custom model bindings or using Action filter.
Based on my test model binder would introduce few additional steps, so for your context I personally prefer ActionFilterAttribute
Let's have a how we could implement with less hassle:
Custom Action Filter:
public class InjectTenantIdFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (context.ActionArguments.TryGetValue("model", out var obj) && obj is RegisterCustomerRequest model)
        {
            if (context.HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("TenentId", out var tenantIdHeader) && int.TryParse(tenantIdHeader, out var tenantId))
            {
                model.TenentId = tenantId.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                context.ModelState.AddModelError("TenentId", "Invalid or missing TenentId header");
            }
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(context);
    }
}

Note: I am extracting the request header and binding the TenentId into my RegisterCustomerRequest model. I have defined it as string, you can do whatever you want.
Model:
public class RegisterCustomerRequest
{
    public int Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string TenentId { get; set; }
}

Controller:
[HttpPost]
[ServiceFilter(typeof(InjectTenantIdFilter))]
public async Task<IActionResult> RegisterCustomer([FromBody] RegisterCustomerRequest model)
{
    // Validate the request if necessary
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    
    return Ok();
}

Program.cs:
builder.Services.AddScoped<InjectTenantIdFilter>();

Using Model Binder:
public class RegisterCustomerRequestModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    private readonly ILogger<RegisterCustomerRequestModelBinder> _logger;

    public RegisterCustomerRequestModelBinder(ILogger<RegisterCustomerRequestModelBinder> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));
        }

        
        var request = bindingContext.HttpContext.Request;
        var tenantIdHeader = request.Headers["TenentId"].ToString();

        using var reader = new StreamReader(request.Body);
        var body = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        var model = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<RegisterCustomerRequest>(body, new JsonSerializerOptions
        {
            PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
        });

        if (model == null)
        {
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Failed();
            return;
        }

        if (int.TryParse(tenantIdHeader, out var tenantId))
        {
            model.TenentId = tenantId.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError("TenentId", "Invalid TenentId header");
        }

        bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(model);
    }
}

Model:
[ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(RegisterCustomerRequestModelBinder))]
public class RegisterCustomerRequest
{
    public int Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string TenentId { get; set; }
}

Controller:
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> RegisterCustomer([ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(RegisterCustomerRequestModelBinder))] RegisterCustomerRequest model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        
        return Ok(model); 
    }

Request:






Note: For any further assistance please check this official document as a reference.
